# How to Make Input Field Carry Text into Google Custom Search on Separate Page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, search

So I added Google Custom Search onto my site, and really like how it is functioning.  One thing though, is that I want to make it so you can just click an input field at the top of the page, search, and have it redirect you to my page: http://www.example.com/search but put what they searched in the normal input field at the top of the page, into the google custom search box and search it.

More or less, this site right here is doing EXACTLY what I am trying to do, I'm not sure if its involving AJAX or what, but I am completely stumped and couldn't find a nice guide on how to do it anywhere.

http://www.a-g.com/ (try searching in the top right to see what I am talking about)

Is there an easy way to do this?  Could anybody point me in the right direction at-least?

Thanks so much, have really been stressing about figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit the search URL with a `q` parameter like this: http://www.northtownsremodeling.com/search.php?q=gallery

So it should basically work by simply submitting a form via GET with a "q" parameter that contains the search string.

Something like:

```
<form method="get" action="/search.php">
    <input name="q">
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/csegM/

Comment: Wow... That was... Surprisingly easy.. I feel embarrassed :X Honestly, thank you SO MUCH, functions absolutely PERFECTLY now, SOOOOOOOO happy, thank you, thank you, thank you! :)

Comment: One last thing, in addition to this, is there a way that I can have it echo what they typed in like static at the top "Search Results for: (what-they-typed-in)"?